# Enable Camera Shutter Sound Switch on roooted Samsung Exynos with Android 9+

Tags: samsung, root-access, camera-sound

This question has been asked a lot of times, but since new versions of Android rolling out the given answers are not accurate any more. The old solution as root was to rename the *.ogg sound files in the **system/media/audio/ui** folder but since Android 9 the sounds are **hardcoded into the Camera App**. On devices in countries where it is forbidden by law to take sneaky pictures (Europe for example) Samsung had to remove the **switch** from the options where you can **disable the Camera Shutter Sound**.

My question is: **how to put back the switch into the Camera App options menu**?

Answer (score 1):

After days of searching I finally found out how to do it. The solution was to change the "cscfeature.xml" file in the folder corresponding to your country code. This file is encrypted, so I've written down a step by step guide. (no xposed or magisk modules needed, only root access to the filesystem):

### add Call Recording en Shutter Sound options to your Exynos phone by adding 2 CSC options to cscfeature.xml

---

1. check your csc code (about phone > software information > service provider sw > last 3 letters: [CSC])
2. in root explorer goto: /system/product/omc/[CSC]/conf/cscfeature.xml
3. download OmcTextDecoder (https://github.com/fei-ke/OmcTextDecoder)
4. put the downloaded "omc-decoder.jar" in a folder together with the encrypted "cscfeature.xml" file on a linux pc
5. open terminal and cd to the folder where you have put the files
6. run: java -jar omc-decoder.jar -i cscfeature.xml -o cscfeature_decoded.xml
7. open the "cscfeature_decoded.xml" file in a text editor
8. add the following lines to the file:

   <CscFeature_VoiceCall_ConfigRecording>RecordingAllowed</CscFeature_VoiceCall_ConfigRecord>
   <CscFeature_Camera_ShutterSoundMenu>TRUE</CscFeature_Camera_ShutterSoundMenu>
9. save the file and rename your old "cscfeature.xml" to "cscfeature_encoded.xml"
10. encode the edited file by running the following command in terminal:
    java -jar omc-decoder.jar -e -i cscfeature_decoded.xml -o cscfeature.xml
11. copy the changed and ecoded file back to your phone: "cscfeature.xml" and backup the old one to "cscfeature.bak"
12. reboot and you will find the shutter switch in the camera settings!

extra options:
https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-features-in-samsung-galaxy-smartphones/